# Start a thread by a button press while another thread is running

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have this code where a stage moves and collects images from a camera while moving. I need a for loop to move the stage a certain amount of steps and at the same time live updating camera image. I get that threading module can be used for this in tkinter. This code is working for the first scan. But is it possible to have a button to start the scanning (start the for loop for the stage) by a button press?

```
def func1():
    global diffposvec
    motor.move_to(movepos[0])
    for count in range (0,Np1):
        movetopos = movepos[count]
        motor.move_to(movetopos)
        act_pos = motor.position
        diffpos = movetopos-act_pos
        diffposvec = []
        diffposvec = np.append(diffposvec,diffpos)
        if np.mod(count,1)==0:
            time.sleep(1)
            print('Step number %.0f' % (count+1),' of %.0f' % Np1, '  %.4f s' % (tic),'   %.3f um' % (act_pos*1000),'   %.3f um' % (movetopos*1000),'   %.3f nm' % (diffpos*1e6))
    root.after(1, func1)

cond = False
def func2():
    global framer
    if (cond == True):
        ax1.cla()
        framer= cammer.grab_image(timeout='1s',copy=True,n_frames=1,exposure_time='5ms',cx=420,
                                                      left=200,cy=600,top=300)
        ax1.imshow(framer)
        canvas1.draw()
root.after(1,func2)

def plot_start():
    global cond
    cond = True

def plot_stop():
    global cond
    cond = False

root.update()
startplot = Button(root, text = "Apply", font=(NormalFont,'16'),borderless=5,height=36,
            foreground='#161327', background="#2AA409", command = lambda: plot_start())
startplot.place(x=10,y=10)

root.update()
stopplot = Button(root, text = "STOP", font= (NormalFont,'16'),borderless=5,height=36,
           foreground='#161327', background="#AA180B", command = lambda: plot_stop())
stopplot.place(x=150,y=10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = func1).start()
    Thread(target = func2).start()
           
    ww = 1000
    hw = 500
            
    w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    h = root.winfo_screenheight() 
    
    x = (w/2) - (ww/2)
    y = (h/2) - (hw/2)-50
        
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (ww, hw, x, y))
    root.update()
    root.mainloop()
```

So func1 is to move the stage and func2 is for the live updating camera image. Right now when I run this program the stage starts scanning and I can see the plot updating, but I need to start func1 function from a button press while the plot is always updating.
Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Can you please fix your indentation?

Comment: Also you should start the loop using `root.after(1, func1)` instead of `Thread(target=func1).start()`. Same thing for `func2`. Also also why is your code running every 1 ms? If you wanted to run it every second use `.adfter(1000, ...)` instead.

Comment: @TheLizzard fixed the indentation, sorry for that. Its either `root.after(1, func1)` or `Thread(target=func1).start()` right? But both doesn't start the thread by a button click